# How to enable HPET on a Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I have been searching for documentation on how to properly enable the HPET on a Hyper-V. I haven't been able to find anything specifying if it works or not, and if it does work, how to properly enable it. From our initial tests, it doesn't seem to be consistent with either the machines timer or the HPET.

We are deploying Lync and UCMA based applications and have noticed a significant performance difference between machines with HPET enable and HPET disabled in terms of their ability to handle capacity. We would like to be able to virtualize these machines, but the HPET is currently our limiting factor.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I don't think we can enable HPET in VM .

Generally for a physical machine we can enable it

1.From BIOS enable HPET

and

2.From OS run `bcdedit /set useplatformclock true` and then reboot.

Comment: It is possible on VMWare Virtual Machines through a configuration property. I'm looking for the solution to Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Microsoft's [Hypervisor Top-Level Functional Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39289), the only references to the HPET I can see relate to the hypervisor's own use of the HPET. It doesn't appear to provide a virtual HPET device.